# Debug chrooted program with gdb

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, chroot

I'm in the situation where the program I have to debug must be run in a chrooted environment. Right now I've installed gdb in the other root and copied the sources over, which works for a rudimentary setup, but isn't very convenient, since I have to resync the source any time I make changes and recompile and I have to copy over all my gdb settings, etc.

Is there any way I can run the debugger in my normal environment, to debug a program that runs in a chrooted environment? I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: If the chroot can access the loopback network, you can use remote debugging.

Comment: When using remote debugging, will source lookup happen at the client side or server side?

Comment: Client side, of course!

Comment: The server side only needs the `gdbserver` and the runtime environment. Technically, it doesn't even need debugging symbols.

Comment: Thanks! You should write that as an actual answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Added an answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use remote debugging:

In the chroot you need just your usual runtime plus the program `gdbserver`. Then run:

```
chroot$ gdbserver :8888 myprogram
```

In the development environment, from the source directory you run `gdb` and connect it to the server

```
$ gdb myprogram
(gdb) target remote :8888
```

And you can start debugging.

I like to do `br main` before `continue` because the debugger will be stopped in `_start`, too early to be useful.

PS: Be aware of the security concerns when using remote debugging, as the 8888 is a listening TCP port.

Comment: Got `(gdb) gdb target :8888
Undefined command: "gdb".  Try "help".`
Is there a specific version of gdb that is required?
Edit: As of gdb/gdbserver version 7.9.1, the command is `target remote :8888`.

Comment: @DarkFranX: That was a typo, see the updated answer.